# Meteor - Strange behavior when using {{#if}} to setup table rows

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to setup a table using alternating row colors. I'm having trouble getting Meteor to let me use the #if statement to start each row.

Here is the simple helper to determine if the row number is odd or even;

```
Template.drillDown.trx = function() {
    return trx.find({userID: Meteor.userId()});
}


Template.drillDown.isEven = function(num) {
  return !( num & 1 );
}
```

and I have this in the template named drillDown;

```
<table>
    {{#each trx}}
        {{#if isEven trx_num}}
            <tr class="even">
        {{else}}
            <tr class="odd">
        {{/if}}
            <td>{{trx_num}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

I get the error unexpected {{else}}. I've tried setting this up other ways where I pass in the entire tag like `<tr class="even">` but then it throws an error when it see's the closing  tag. Any suggestions on how to get past this problem?

Comment: How does trx helper looks?

Comment: I'll add it in up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are wrapping just the start tag in the `{{#if}}` block. In Spacebars, everything has to be a complete element with a start and end tag.

The best way to accomplish what you're looking for is:

Helper:

```
Template.drillDown.isEven = function() {
  return !( this.trx_num & 1 );
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr class="{{#if isEven}}even{{else}}odd{{/if}}">
  <td>{{trx_num}}</td>
</tr>
```

Also, you could avoid this whole matter entirely and use `tr:nth-child(even)` instead of even and odd classes: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: I plopped your code in there and it works perfectly. First I've heard of tr:nth-child(even), still learing new things after all these years. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would change `if` helper like this:

```
Template.drillDown.isEven = function() {
  return !( this.trx_num & 1 );
}
```

(I assume helper returns correct answer)
Then, `if` statement can look like this, cause I guess this line causes trouble

```
{{#if isEven}}
```

Also, if you have more helpers, better way to manage them is to keep them this way

```
Template.<template>.helpers({  
        isEven: function() {
            return !( this.trx_num & 1 ); 
        },
        trx: function() {
           return trx.find({userID: Meteor.userId()});
        },
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I'll use it!